# Hex to plain ASCII? Python 2.7.13

Tags: python, hex

Im trying to turn this:
%73%6c%61%70%72%69%73%65%40%6c%69%65%6e%6d%75%6c%74%69%6d%65%64%69%61%2e%63%6f%6d

into this:
slaprise@lienmultimedia.com

and my brain is exploding.. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: It is not hex encoded string. It is url encoded string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python 2.7.17 (should work for Python 2.7.13)

```
import urllib2

url = urllib2.unquote("%73%6c%61%70%72%69%73%65%40%6c%69%65%6e%6d%75%6c%74%69%6d%65%64%69%61%2e%63%6f%6d")
print(url)
# slaprise@lienmultimedia.com
```

Comment: If the answer solved the problem you were having, [please accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to URL-decode that string, use urllib:

```
from urllib import unquote

url = unquote("%73%6c%61%70%72%69%73%65%40%6c%69%65%6e%6d%75%6c%74%69%6d%65%64%69%61%2e%63%6f%6d")
# url = slaprise@lienmultimedia.com
```

Comment: Your solution will not work for Python2.7

Comment: @narendra-choudhary I've updated my code, btw I think he can still use urllib